# replace <constructor-arg> with Spring Annotation

Tags: java, spring, generics, annotations, code-injection

there is a way to replace constructor-arg with Annotation?

I have this constructor:

```
public GenericDAOImpl(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

and i need to inject that in my Facade:

```
@Inject
private GenericDAO<Auto, Long> autoDao;
```

The problem is that i don't know how to pass the value of parameter in costructor.

Thank you in advance

[More Info]
I try to explain my problem.

```
<bean id="personDao" class="genericdao.impl.GenericDaoHibernateImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>genericdaotest.domain.Person</value>
        </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I want convert that code using only annotation.
Someone can explain how?

Answer (score 4):

I think `@Inject` alone won't help, you will have to use a `@Qualifier` annotation also.

Here's the relevant Section of the Spring Reference:
[**3.9.3 Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

If I understand this correctly, you will have to use the `@Qualifier` mechanism.

If you use [Spring's `@Qualifier` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html), you can probably do it inline, something like this:

```
@Repository
public class DaoImpl implements Dao{

    private final Class<?> type;

    public DaoImpl(@Qualifier("type") final Class<?> type){
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

But if you use the [JSR-330 `@Qualifier` annotation](http://atinject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/javax/inject/Qualifier.html), I guess you will have to create your own custom annotation that is marked with `@Qualifier`.

---

Another possibility would be the [`@Value`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation. With it you can use Expression Language, e.g. like this:

```
public DaoImpl(
    @Value("#{ systemProperties['dao.type'] }")
    final Class<?> type){
    this.type = type;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** I'm afraid it is not possible to do what you are trying to. You can't get constructor arguments from the parameters of the injection point. A `FactoryBean` would be the first place to look, but it isn't given the injection point metadata. (To be noted: this case is easily covered by CDI)

**Original answer:** (that may still work if you configure your types externally)

Simply use `@Inject` on the constructor. But note that spring frowns upon constructor injection. Consider setter/field injection.

In your case, however, you're likely to have more than one beans of type `Class`. If this is the case, you can use `@Resource(name="beanName")`.

From the docs of [`javax.inject.Inject`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html):

> Injectable constructors are annotated with @Inject and accept zero or more dependencies as arguments. @Inject can apply to at most one constructor per class.
>
> ```
>    @Inject ConstructorModifiersopt SimpleTypeName(FormalParameterListopt)  
>    Throwsopt ConstructorBody
> ```

Comment: I already use @Inject, but i need to pass the value of Class<T> type too. There is a way to do it? or i must use xml approach?

Comment: what is that value? Where do you get it from?

Comment: @Inject
private GenericDAO<Auto, Long> autoDao; when the GenericDAO was istantiated i need to pass the value of Class<T> type

Answer (score 2):

An option to have the type in your constructor is:

```
public abstract class GenericDAO<T> {
    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    public GenericDAO() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
...
}
```

but MUST have specific different implementations for each T.

Advantage is that you don't need to pass T type as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Spring's [Java Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) might be of help here. If you create a Java class that simply defines your beans using the annotations `@Configuration` and `@Bean` it could look something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class DaoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public GenericDAO<Person> personDao() {
        return new GenericDaoHibernateImpl(Person.class);
    }
}
```

Make sure that the `DaoConfiguration` class is scanned (typically via `@ComponentScan`) and a proper DAO-object will be created for you in the Spring context. The bean will have the name of the method which in this case is `personDao` so you can inject it *by name* using the name `personDao` or *by type* if the type is `GenericDAO<Person>`.