# Spring : how to replace constructor-arg by annotation?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [replace <constructor-arg> with Spring Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614349/replace-constructor-arg-with-spring-annotation)

i would like to replace an XML applicationContext configuration by an annotation.

How to replace a simple bean with constructor arguments which are fixed ?

Exemple :

```
<bean id="myBean" class="test.MyBean">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="$MYDIR/myfile.xml"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="$MYDIR/myfile.xsd"/>
</bean>
```

I'm reading some explanation on @Value, but i don't really understand how to pass some fixed values...

Is it possible to load this bean when the web application is deployed ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think what you are after is this:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    private String xmlFile;
    private String xsdFile;

    @Autowired
    public MyBean(@Value("$MYDIR/myfile.xml") final String xmlFile,
            @Value("$MYDIR/myfile.xsd") final String xsdFile) {
        this.xmlFile = xmlFile;
        this.xsdFile = xsdFile;
    }

    //methods
}
```

You also might want these files to be configurable via system properties.  You can use the `@Value` annotation to read system properties using the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, and the `${}` syntax.

To do this, you can use different `String` values in your `@Value` annotation:

```
@Value("${my.xml.file.property}")
@Value("${my.xsd.file.property}")
```

but you will also need these properties in your system properties:

```
my.xml.file.property=$MYDIR/myfile.xml
my.xsd.file.property=$MYDIR/myfile.xsd
```

Comment: time to switch to groovy config