# Inject values into map using spring annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring. Mostly I will inject the components and services. But now I want to initialize a map with enum key and injected values of the the "Cache" implementation so that given the enum I can get the object to refresh cache.

```
Map<String,Cache>

Key           Value
"category"    @Inject Category     
"attr"        @Inject Attr
"country"     @Inject Country
```

My class are like

```
public abstract class Cache{
    refreshCache() {
      clearCache();
      createCache();
    }
    clearCache();
    createCache();
}

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
@Qualifier("category")
class Category extends Cache{}

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
@Qualifier("attr")
class Attr extends Cache{}

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
@Qualifier("country")
class Country extends Cache{}
```

It can be done by XML (Like bellow or at [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-collections-list-set-map-and-properties-example/)) but i want to do it with annotations.

```
<property name="maps">
        <map>
            <entry key="Key 1" value="1" />
            <entry key="Key 2" value-ref="PersonBean" />
            <entry key="Key 3">
                <bean class="com.mkyong.common.Person">
                    <property name="name" value="mkyongMap" />
                    <property name="address" value="address" />
                    <property name="age" value="28" />
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
```

Comment: I'm not sure (didn't used in such way), but did you tried `@Bean` methods?

Comment: NO i havent used it for that as in i am not able to map how can i use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have the following beans in your Spring context:

```
@Component("category")
class Category extends Cache { }

@Component("attr")
class Attr extends Cache { }

@Component("country")
class Country extends Cache { }
```

Note that there's no need to explicitly set scope to singleton, since this is the default in Spring. Besides, there's no need to use `@Qualifier`; it's enough to set the bean name via `@Component("beanName")`.

The most simple way to inject singleton bean instances to a map is as follows:

```
@Autowired
Map<String, Cache> map;
```

This will effectively autowire all subclasses of `Cache` to the map, with the key being the bean name.

Comment: @Shivay Make sure you are scanning cache subclasses and that the map is a field of another Spring bean that is also being scanned.

Answer (score -1):

You can get this done using Spring Expression Language.

I have transformed your below map definition:

```
<property name="maps">
    <map>
        <entry key="Key 1" value="1" />
        <entry key="Key 2" value-ref="PersonBean" />
        <entry key="Key 3">
            <bean class="com.mkyong.common.Person">
                <property name="name" value="mkyongMap" />
                <property name="address" value="address" />
                <property name="age" value="28" />
            </bean>
        </entry>
    </map>
</property>
```

to annotation based. Below is the code:

### PersonBean

```
@Component("PersonBean")
public class PersonBean {
    public String getMessage() {
        return "hello!";
    }
}
```

### Person

```
package com.mkyong.common;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

### PersonConfiguration

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.mkyong.common.Person;

@Configuration
public class PersonConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Person person() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("mkyongMap");
        person.setAddress("address");
        person.setAge(28);
        return person;
    }
}
```

### TestController

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.mkyong.common.Person;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Value("#{{'Key 1':1, 'Key 2':@PersonBean, 'Key 3': @person}}")
    Map testMap;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public void testMethod() {
        System.out.println(testMap.get("Key 1"));
        PersonBean personBean = (PersonBean) testMap.get("Key 2");
        System.out.println(personBean.getMessage());
        Person person = (Person) testMap.get("Key 3");
        System.out.println("Name: " + person.getName() + ", Address: "
                + person.getAddress() + ", Age: " + person.getAge());
    }

}
```

Comment: Can i use it for the above problem like

Comment: I explored this for solving your question and this works!

Comment: can you tell me how can I inject the values. Instead of "new" coz the bean need to be singleton. Or it doesn't matter as in the spring is instantiating.

Comment: If you would need to make it singleton, you may look for static method call in the reference manual. If you would need to use Spring injection, define it as a bean and use the `@` definition.

Comment: You may look into this reference to create Spring Beans with constructor args    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725165/spring-how-to-replace-constructor-arg-by-annotation

Comment: @AdrianMenendez, either you got a problem with Mkyong or with me. Please read the question and see what I have written. You might be the person who copies from other sites.