# Map size different than actual entries

Tags: java, spring

I have tried to autowire a number of classes to a map, using the technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715156/inject-values-into-map-using-spring-annotation). Here are the code samples :

```
// How are the implementation classes stored inside the map described
@Component("mapperOne")
public class DataMapper extends AbstractMapper  {
    ...
}

// The abstract class, implementing the interface
public abstract class AbstractMapper implements Mapper<T>  {
    ...
}

// Where the bug is actually occuring
public class MapperFactory {

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, Mapper<T>>  mapperMap;

    public void getMapper(String mapper)    {
        ...
        Mapper<T> mapper = mapperMap.get(mapper);
        ...
    }
}
```

I know I have 6 mappers referenced with the `@Component` annotation, however the data showed in Debug mode are inaccurate:

- The `size` of the Map is 6, the `modCount` is 6.
- The `head` references the first mapper of the list.
- **The `table` of the map only shows 3 values out of the 6.**
- The `tail` of the map isn't even in the `table` !
- The `keySet` correctly shows the 6 entries of my map.

[image: If you want the visual, here it is]

This problem brings a `NullPointerException` because I tried to access a mapper which is not in the map (despite appearing in the `keySet`). I notice that Spring uses a `LinkedHashMap` to autowire those fields, and I don't know if it has any consequence.

What is happening there ? I can't figure out. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

---

**EDIT**

> Looks like hash collisions, so nothing going wrong there. If hashcode % table.size lands on the same index for 2 keys, their values will end up in the same bucket. You get a sort of linked list of entries at the same index. Are you sure the key you use is right ?

I ran the following code snippet:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Mapper<T>> entry : mapperMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.hashCode() % mapperMap.size());
}
```

Which gave me the following result:

```
firstKey : -1
secondKey : -5
thirdKey : 5
fourthKey : -1
fifthKey : 2
sixthKey : 0
```

So we have a collision on one index only (`first` and `fourth`). I had another dissapearance after a while, so now my map only contains `firstKey` and `thirdKey` as a concrete implementations.

Comment: Looks like hash collisions, so nothing going wrong there. If `hashcode % table.size` lands on the same index for 2 keys, their values will end up in the same bucket. You get a sort of linked list of entries at the same index. Are you sure the key you use is right?

Comment: Well, I am sure the keys are unique on their own. I would find it rather strange that it would land on the same index for 3 classes ouf of 6, but it is a possibility. I don't have much tracks to follow anyway.

Comment: You should be able to check by looking at the `Entry.next` field, which would be the next entry in the same bucket.

Comment: Hmm, it is strange. `Entry.next` shows the next entry, which is correctly instantiated (`Entry.next.value` shows the actual Java object), even thought it skips it because it does not exist in the table.